# Create a video of layered videos

Tags: python, opencv, video, overlap

I'm a python and OpenCV beginner!
I would like to create a video made of 3 others videos. Each video is a moving car on a black background

I created the video which is empty for the moment:

```
video_summary=cv2.VideoWriter(video_output_path ,fourcc,video_fps ,(480,270), True)
```

Now, I would like to add videos called 0, 2 and 4 from "video_a_ajouter" in video_summary.

```
video_a_ajouter=[0,2,4]
video_working=[]
```

So, I did this:

```
for i in video_a_ajouter:    video_working.append(cv2.VideoCapture(output_directory_path+'output_TP_'+str(video_a_ajouter[0])+'.avi'))
        video_a_ajouter.remove(video_a_ajouter[0])
```

I would like to know how to put the 3 videos in video_summary, considering that 0 overlaps 2 and 2 overlaps 4

Thank you in advance for your help !! :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually, what I would like to do is to merge the videos: I would like to see the 3 cars of each video at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "made of 3 other videos", here are 2 ideas:

1) the 3 videos are seen one after another in succession:

If this is the case, you can check which if the current video is finished. If it isn't, add its frame, else append the frame from the next video:

```
ret1,img1=cap1.read()//read 1st video
ret2,img2=cap2.read()//2nd
ret3,img3=cap3.read()//3rd

if(cap1.isOpened()):
   video_summary.write(img1)
elif(cap2.isOpened()):
   video_summary.write(img2)
elif(cap3.isOpened()):
   video_summary.write(img3)
```

2) you need to overlay the 3 videos one over another:

In this case, you should look up the addWeighted function